# setInterval calling function having setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially `moto` is hidden 10s;
After 10s it should be visible.
Stay visible - 15 sec.
Hide

and again:
- hidden 10s...

Here si my try, without success - `moto` is never shown.

```js
function go_anima(){
 $("#moto").hide();
 setTimeout(function(){$("#moto").fadeIn();}, 10000);
}

   $(document).on('ready', function(){
 setInterval(function(){go_anima();}, 25000);
});
```

```css
.moto{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='moto' id='moto'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
```

Comment: It works for me. But note that you're not calling `go_anima` until the first interval occurs, after 25 seconds. Since it starts hidden, and then when that fires it hides it for another 10 seconds, that means you initially won't see the div for 35 seconds before it fades in. After that, it will follow the pattern you want.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, I'm on Chrome and been waiting even 5  minutes - nothing happend.

Comment: Very strange. I just copied it into a CodePen and after 35 seconds, it faded into view correctly. Sorry I can't help more, but if I can't reproduce the issue, I have no starting point for helping you fix it.

Comment: That is not how you debug, @qadenza. You should add in some `console.log` in your code, to check what parts are executed. And limit the timeouts to just 500ms and 1 second, to avoid waiting each time. You'll soon notice, that nothing actually executes.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, give me the link to your CodePen, pls

Comment: https://codepen.io/icemetalpunk/pen/ZEYXWGe

Comment: @qadenza It doesn't make sense to "self-correct" your question, because now the answer doesn't make sense (or is harder to understand), please roll back to previous version, if you agree...

Comment: @Vickel, you're right, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "ready" event<sup>1</sup> emitted by the document:

```
 $(document).on('ready', function(){
```

Instead you need the `ready` *method*:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

Or, preferred, just:

```
 $(function(){
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The "ready" event was available in older jQuery versions, as stated in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.

Comment: Using `.on('ready', ...` works in my CodePen test, though, so jQuery seems more than capable of listening for that event... Though admittedly I forked it from a 2.1.3 jQuery playground pen, so maybe there's a difference.

Comment: I updated my answer. Your CodePen uses jQuery 2, where this deprecated functionality was still included.